# Double arrows in tikzcd

Tags: tikz-cd

please look at below example:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        x_1(k+1) \arrow{d}{x_1(k)} & \\
        x_2(k+1) \arrow{d}{x_2(k)} & x_4(k+1) \arrow{lu}{x_1(k)} \arrow{l}{x_2(k)} \arrow[loop right]{l}{x_4(k)} \\
        x_3(k+1) \arrow[ru, equal]{x_3(k)} & \\
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
```

and output:

[image: output]

The problem is that I want to get arrows in two sides in that double line (between x_3(k+1) and x_4(k+1)). How can I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add the arrow and shift it. I'd give some more room to the diagram and change side for most of the labels.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=3em,column sep=3em]
x_1(k+1) \arrow[d,swap,"x_1(k)"] & \\
x_2(k+1) \arrow[d,swap,"x_2(k)"] &
  x_4(k+1)
  \arrow[lu,swap,"x_1(k)"]
  \arrow[l,swap,"x_2(k)"]
  \arrow[l,loop right,"x_4(k)"]
  \arrow[dl,shift right]
 \\
x_3(k+1) \arrow[ru,shift right,swap,"x_3(k)"]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is what I needed! In new document, everything is ok, but when I put it into my work, I'm getting several errors:
linia 272: Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }. \end{tikzcd}
linia 272: Paragraph ended before \language@active@arg" was complete. \end{tikzcd}
linia 272: Paragraph ended before \pgfkeys@addpath was complete. \end{tikzcd}
linia 272: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end{tikzcd}
linia 272: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end{tikzcd}
linia 272: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end{tikzcd}
linia 272: Paragraph ended before \pgfkeys@splitter was complete. \end{tikzcd}

Comment: And it's compile, but without x_i(k) on the arrows.

Comment: @ktatar156 What language are you loading `babel` with?

Comment: @ktatar156 Add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` after `\usepackage{tikz-cd}` and all should go well.

Answer (score 5):

Is the `Leftrightarrow` arrow type what you're after?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        x_1(k+1) \arrow{d}{x_1(k)} & \\
        x_2(k+1) \arrow{d}{x_2(k)} & x_4(k+1) \arrow{lu}{x_1(k)} \arrow{l}{x_2(k)} \arrow[loop right]{l}{x_4(k)} \\
        x_3(k+1) \arrow[ru, Leftrightarrow]{x_3(k)} & \\
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]