# A problem with drawing a diagram arrow

Tags: tikz-cd

Attached a code in latex. I want to draw a (dashed) arrow from $ R' $ into $ R_S $, but the arrow I define is always merged with the arrow from $ R_S $. How can I do it?

```
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
S \arrow[r, "i_R"] \arrow[d, "\phi| _S"]
   & R \arrow [r,"\tau"] \arrow[d,"\phi"] & R_S  \arrow[dl,dashed,"\exists !\phi'"]   \\
(R')^{*} \arrow [r,"i_{R'}"] 
   & R' % \arrow [ur,dashed,"\exists !\tau'" yshift=-2.5ex]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay, I found it here:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308859/double-arrows-in-tikzcd. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shift both diagonal arrows; I also suggest to swap the label in the vertical arrows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
S \arrow[r, "i_R"] \arrow[d, "\phi| _S"']
   & R \arrow[r,"\tau"] \arrow[d,"\phi"']
   & R_S \arrow[dl,dashed,"\exists !\phi'",shift left=0.5ex] \\
(R')^{*} \arrow[r,"i_{R'}"]
   & R'  \arrow[ur,dashed,"\exists !\tau'",shift left=0.5ex]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

(Sorry, but at the moment I cannot add images for technical reasons)

You can swap the two diagonal arrows by shifting them right and swapping the label position.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
S \arrow[r,"i_R"] \arrow[d,"\phi| _S"']
   & R \arrow[r,"\tau"] \arrow[d,"\phi"']
   & R_S  \arrow[dl,dashed,"\exists !\phi'\!"',shift right=0.5ex] \\
(R')^{*} \arrow[r,"i_{R'}"]
   & R'  \arrow[ur,dashed,"\exists !\tau'"', shift right=0.5ex]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's okay, how can I put the $R' \to R_S$  bellow the first one?Thanks

Comment: Alright, I checked it again, and I don't need it.

Comment: @IamnotPaulErdos I swapped the diagonal arrows anyhow

Comment: Alright thanks. I found that it's negligible and prefered not to bother you for it, but that's still better