# hello! could you help me to draw this diagram in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

[image]

quiver diagram in latex drawing

Comment: Welcome, how far did you get? This is not a *draw this for me for free* service.

Comment: This should get you quite far: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191462/creating-triangle-commutative-diagram-with-tikz-cd This demonstrates how to make a loop in `tikz-cd`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364415/how-to-make-loop-smaller-in-tikz-cd And this gives some hint how to get two arrows: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/308863/586

Comment: Welcome to TeX! Please view our [help] and take the [tour] when you have a moment. Thank you!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 12):

You can use `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
&
2 \arrow[dl,swap,"\beta"]
\\
1 \arrow[rr,shift left,"\lambda"]
  \arrow[rr,shift right,swap,"\mu"]
&&
3 \arrow[ul,swap,"\alpha"]
  \arrow[loop,out=30,in=330,looseness=10,"\gamma"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The original appears to have been done using [`xy-pic`](https://www.tug.org/applications/Xy-pic/).

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@C=1in{
& 
2 
\ar @<-.5ex> [dl]_\beta 
& 
\\
1 
\ar @<+.5ex> [rr]^\lambda 
\ar @<-.5ex> [rr]_\mu 
&& 
3 
\ar @<-.5ex> [lu]_\alpha
\ar @(ur,rd) []^\gamma
\\
}
\end{document}
```

Try `texdoc xypic` for more documentation, or follow the link above.